# Odd Font Border w/ No CSS Applied

Tags: html, css

I've taken out all of the styles on a page, and I'm still seeing this really odd font border issue.  All of the text is really weighted, and I've ran out of things to debug.  Here is what it looks like close up:

[image]

See the light blue and tan edges?  That's what it looks like close up, but at 100% it just makes all of the text look really dark and weighted.  Oddly enough the only fix I've been able to find is changing the z-index of a certain element(a header), but that won't work for the long term b/c it renders the header unclickable.  I'm using Chrome 36 on OSX, and it turns out that this occurs even with as simple a page as:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="">link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Please paste a working demo so we can see your styles.

Comment: are you using @font-face? are you on chrome? sample code?

Comment: please paste you working code

Comment: All browsers render fonts differently. Please specify what browser.

Comment: Have added sample markup and info on browser(Chrome 36) and OS(OSX) into the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a border, that's the lcd smoothing algorithm.  It works by assuming a particular orientation of RGB cells on the LCD monitor, so it can turn on e.g. 1/3 of a pixel at a time for a "smoother" font.  You can turn off smoothing in Windows by disabling "ClearType", but know that your viewers are likely to have it enabled.

References:

- http://szafranek.net/works/articles/font-smoothing-explained/
- http://www.davidjnice.com/articles/windows7_disableClearType.html

Comment: Thank you!  Why would similar markup/css on the same computer(Chrome/OSX) display differently then?  Isn't ClearType a system-wide setting?  I'm in the process of redesigning something, and the old design's text doesn't have the smoothing algorithm applied, but after changing some css, it is now applied to the new design.  If it were a system-wide setting, both should display text the same correct?

Comment: Read the first reference completely.  It's a bit dated, but describes how smoothing is not universally applied in browser rendering engines, and how there might be a future implementation of a "font-smoothing" CSS3 parameter, which might be implemented by now in some cases.